# Change wording "Special Price" & "Regular Price" in Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am trying to change the wording "Special Price" and "Regular Price" in Magento. I've already tried editing the Mage_Catalogue.csv, reuploading and clearing the cache to no avail. I've also done a giant Dreamweaver search within the entire site for the text "Regular" and "Special" and haven't found anything.

I can only conclude that this may be hidden somewhere deep in one of 200 DB tables...

If anybody knows where I might be able to change these values I'd be forever grateful.

Thank you

Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the locale/internationalisation stuff.

A handy tool is the inline translater - this can be turned on via System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline. You can then update text by clicking on it.

Comment: Woah, that's amazingly useful! Thanks

Comment: The inline translater is great but "Special Price" can not be translated with this tool.

Answer (score 8):

Please go to <kbd>Admin</kbd> >> <kbd>Catalog</kbd> >> <kbd>Attributes</kbd> , then find a attribute code `special_price`. Edit this attribute, click to tab : <kbd>Manage Label and Option</kbd> , at here You can change text of `special_price` for each store view.

Answer (score 6):

> app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

This is the file that controls the prices. You'll find the Special and Regular there. There are a few more files in the Product/View folder - price.phtml, price_clone.phtml, tierprices.phtml

Read through them. Magento uses a different price type for each type of product (Simple, Config, Group, etc)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another possibility is to change the value in the Locale file. In app/locale/en_US find the Mage_Catalog.csv file and change the values
"Special Price","Special Price"
"Special Price:","Special Price:"
"Regular Price:","Regular Price:"

Because Magento uses internationalisation, the customer will see the value you set here.

I wouldn't do this method as you will have to keep moving the locale file as well. Best is to duplicate the template and change it there in the price.phtml file.

Comment: Ahhhh - price.phtml is perfect. I think my Dreamweaver find/replace didn't work because I'm on a fresh install and hadn't yet associates .phtml with DR. Thank-you!

Answer (score 2):

Other choice, you can modify our price.phml with :

search:
    $_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();

replace with:

```
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->__($this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel());
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your tax settings, you might also need to change:

```
<?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?>
```

into

```
<?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?>
```

in order for the CSV translation file approach to work.

Comment: This was our problem ... very unexpected .. what does special price have to do with tax?

Answer (score 0):

In your theme directory (ex: app/design/frontend/[theme]/default you can add a directory called locale and then make a translate.csv file.  In column A of the CSV put Special Price: and column B the update that you want made ex:

Special Price:,Sale Price:

This is probably the better way to do it over the above comment from Sid Vel as this is specific to your theme and will not ruin anything when upgrading as you are not editing a core file.

Answer (score -1):

There is an extension Called PHProTranslate from PHPPro.be found in Magento Connect

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/phpro-translate.html

This extension allows you to search for, and modify EVERYTHING front and back end.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ive updated my comment to refer to the Developer Company directly too.  This is the solution I used without the need for CSV's or code editing and makes the process easily reversible too.  This IS the complete answer.